# Video thumbnails in WP7

Tags: c#, .net, windows-phone-7

I'm currently working on a WP7-app that uses the camera recorder functionality. 
After recording I want to be able to show a temporary thumbnail of the video content.

How do I do this in WP7?

Answer (score 2):

You may find the following a good starting point "How VideoCamera/PhotoCamera content is saved on Windows Phone 7" :-

http://dotnet.dzone.com/articles/how-videocameracamera-content